# Shrinking the base field of an affine variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, finite-differences, field-extensions

This is a question on algebraic geometry/commutative algebra.
Let $K,L$ be fields of characteristics zero and let $K\subset L$ be a field extension (I am interested in the case when this is transcendental).
Assume that there are elements $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_k\in{\rm Gal}(L/K)$ so that $K=\{ a\in L\mid \forall i,\  \sigma_i(a)=a\}$.

We consider a polynomial ring $L[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and an ideal $I$ of it.
Assume $I$ is invariant by $\sigma_i$, i.e., the ideal $I_i:=\{ p^{\sigma_i}\mid p\in I\}$ is equal to $I$ for any $i$.
Here, $p^{\sigma_i}$ is an element of $L[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ obtained from $p$ by replacement $ax^\alpha\mapsto \sigma_i(a)x^\alpha$ $(a\in L)$.
Is it true that there exists an ideal $I_0\subset K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that its extension $L\otimes_KI_0\subset L[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ is equal to $I$?

I do not know what this type of problem is called. I checked Hartshorne and found exercise 8 in Chap 2.Section 4 which is close to our setup. Unfortunately, it is when $L=\mathbb{C}$, $K=\mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma$ is the complex conjugate. I think the solution to this exercise relies on the fact that $\sigma$ is an involution so I do not know how to generalize it.

Background: I am interested in an affine variety defined over $L=\mathbb{C}(s)\supset \mathbb{C}=K$, where $s$ is a new variable. $\sigma:L\to L$ is the shift operator $s\mapsto s+1$. I guess that the statement above is true at least in this setup.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This is *descent theory* or more specifically *Galois descent theory*.  There is a very readable exposition in Milne's Algebraic Geometry notes, Chapter 16 in https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ag.html. The pdf file is: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG16.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment. Is the exact proposition I should read Proposition 16.8 of the note? Is there any "proper reference" on descent theory? I mean which paper/book do people refer to when they use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard reference is Chapter 6 of "Neron Models" of Bosch, Lütkebohmert and Raynaud, Springer, 1990. The original Grothendieck's exposés in the Cartan Seminar (1960--1961) are available at Numdam: http://www.numdam.org/?lang=en. Milne's notes in https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG16.pdf as I noted before are quite readable. Proposition 16.8 could be what you need, and the general case is in Section g. There is also an exposition in Section 4 of K. Conrad's https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisdescent.pdf.

Comment: Thank you for the very friendly guidance! I will refer to one of these standard texts! Indeed, Milne's exposition is also quite friendly!